# Cygwin xclip fails without cygXmu-6.dll

Tags: cygwin, x11

Tried to install xclip running as administrator, but Got this:

```
    $ apt-cyg install xclip
Installing xclip
xclip-0.12-2.tar.xz: OK
Unpacking...
Package xclip requires the following packages, installing:
bash coreutils cygwin gzip libX11_6 libXmu6 tar
Package bash is already installed, skipping
Package coreutils is already installed, skipping
Package cygwin is already installed, skipping
Package gzip is already installed, skipping
Package libX11_6 is already installed, skipping
Package libXmu6 is already installed, skipping
Package tar is already installed, skipping
Package xclip installed

Tommy@Tommy-PC ~
$ xclip
C:/opt/cygwin64/bin/xclip.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygXmu-6.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

So I removed all the X11 libraries and tried reinstalling. but that gave an even less helpful error:

```
Tommy@Tommy-PC ~
$ apt-cyg remove libXmu6 libX11_6 libX11_6 libXt6
Removing libXmu6
Package libXmu6 removed
Removing libX11_6
Package libX11_6 removed
Package libX11_6 is not installed, skipping
Removing libXt6
Package libXt6 removed

Tommy@Tommy-PC ~
$ apt-cyg install libXmu6 libX11_6 libX11_6 libXt6
Installing libXmu6
libXmu6-1.1.2-1.tar.xz: OK
Unpacking...
Package libXmu6 requires the following packages, installing:
cygwin libX11_6 libXext6 libXt6
Package cygwin is already installed, skipping
Installing libX11_6
--2018-05-22 09:45:18--  http://cygwin.mirror.constant.com//x86_64/release/libX11/libX11_6/libX11_6-1.6.5-1.tar.xz
Resolving cygwin.mirror.constant.com... 108.61.5.83
Connecting to cygwin.mirror.constant.com|108.61.5.83|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 750980 (733K) [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: `libX11_6-1.6.5-1.tar.xz'

libX11_6-1.6.5-1.ta 100%[===================>] 733.38K  1.11MB/s    in 0.6s

2018-05-22 09:45:19 (1.11 MB/s) - `libX11_6-1.6.5-1.tar.xz' saved [750980/750980]

libX11_6-1.6.5-1.tar.xz: OK
Unpacking...
Package libX11_6 requires the following packages, installing:
cygwin libxcb1
Package cygwin is already installed, skipping
Package libxcb1 is already installed, skipping
Package libXext6 is already installed, skipping
Installing libXt6
libXt6-1.1.5-1.tar.xz: OK
Unpacking...
Package libXt6 requires the following packages, installing:
cygwin libICE6 libSM6 libX11_6
Package cygwin is already installed, skipping
Package libICE6 is already installed, skipping
Package libSM6 is already installed, skipping
Package libX11_6 is already installed, skipping
Package libXmu6 installed
Package libX11_6 is already installed, skipping
Package libX11_6 is already installed, skipping
Package libXt6 is already installed, skipping

Tommy@Tommy-PC ~
$ xclip
C:/opt/cygwin64/bin/xclip.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Maybe I can try compiling from source or  use the Cygwin installer?

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way to install a package is to use cygwin setup.
apt-cyg may be convenient but it is NOT an official package.

The canonical way to verify a package installation is to use cygcheck.

```
$ cygcheck -c libX11_6
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
libX11_6             1.6.5-1        OK
```

and if we simulate the damage of the package

```
$ mv /usr/bin/cygX11-6.dll /usr/bin/cygX11-6.dll.tmp

$ cygcheck -cv libX11_6
Cygwin Package Information
Last downloaded files to: e:\downloads\cygwin_cache
Last downloaded files from: http://mirrors.kernel.org/sourceware/cygwin/

Package              Version        Status
Missing file: /usr/bin/cygX11-6.dll from package libX11_6
libX11_6             1.6.5-1        Incomplete
```

You can also use the cygcheck-dep package to interrogate the dependencies, eg:

```
$ cygcheck-dep -r xwinclip
# /usr/bin/cygcheck-dep:
 xwinclip: requires ( cygwin libX11_6 libXfixes3 )
```

Comment: The use of "canonical" to typify the "correct" usage is interesting. But the real reason to leave off using apt-cyg is the [link](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11019970) squabble between the developers that has caused its development to discontinue.

Comment: I used it as `apt-cyg` is not an official cygwin package, so it is not supported by the people involved in the cygwin project.

Comment: You are correct. It was so much easier to use than setup.exe, but life is often complicated by other peoples wars big and small.